# tally odbc xml export ( Timed out )

Tags: xml, vba, tally

used send this xml through odbc

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.send (TallyString)
```

but returned timed out error with large data.
have no problem with small data. and tried different xmls . please help me to solve the error

```
</HEADER>

<BODY>

<EXPORTDATA>

<REQUESTDESC>

<STATICVARIABLES>

<SVFROMDATE>20200401</SVFROMDATE>

<SVTODATE>20210331</SVTODATE>

<VOUCHERTYPENAME>Purchase</VOUCHERTYPENAME>

<EXPLODEFLAG>No</EXPLODEFLAG>

<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName: XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>

</STATICVARIABLES>

<REPORTNAME>Voucher Register</REPORTNAME>

</REQUESTDESC>

</EXPORTDATA>

</BODY>

</ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 Options

### **[Increase Timeout Limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-settimeouts)**

```
objHTTP.SetTimeouts 300000, 300000, 300000, 300000
```

It will be milliseconds so If you want 5 minute Timeout then 5 * 60 * 1000
If you want more then calculate accordingly

If you see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-settimeouts) we are more concerned about 3rd parameter(Send Timeout)

By default send Timeout will be 30 seconds only , Since you are requesting large data from tally, Tally will take more time and request getting timeout

---

### **Getting data from Tally in small parts (Recommended)**

Instead of Getting Whole Year Data at once, Depending on Number of Vouchers we can fetch either Quarterly, Monthly, Weekly ,Daily

Comment: With large data, tally is also being crashed. so will opt for 2nd option. will fetch data in parts and combine. Thank you once again

Comment: That is the reason , I recommend second approach